# how to hide a blank textview

Tags: android, json, listview

so i have a JSON parser
and on it i want to detect blank textviews and then if its blank change that linearlayouts visibility to gone

this is the code i am using but it gives a NullExceptionError

```
    TextView fajr;
    fajr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fajr_iqamah_time);
    if(fajr.getText().toString().length()>0)
    {
        findViewById(R.id.fajr_iqamah).setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
```

logcat :

```
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sahaab.android.muslimzone.test/com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity.IqamahActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at com.sahaab.muslimzone.activity.IqamahActivity.onCreate(IqamahActivity.java:124)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-28 21:29:29.072: E/AndroidRuntime(31039):    ... 12 more
```

basically the textview is in the listViewItems layout, and this class uses the ListView's layout (FragmentActivity due to also having map)

layout and 2 activity classes
https://www.dropbox.com/s/erigyxk6jp5bpct/Desktop.rar

Comment: The set visibility call is fine.  Its not finding a view with that id.  Make sure that its not hidden in a fragment and that your id is correct.

Comment: this is a activity
and id is correct
shud i create a adapter for the listview? and if so how shud i do it?

Comment: Um, every list view needs an adaptor.  But this has nothing to do with it-  it can't find the view with that id.  Is that id supposed to exist inside your list view?  In that case it doesn't exist yet, those get inflated in getView of the adaptor.

Comment: this is the java class and the 2 layouts
could you please check??
https://www.dropbox.com/s/erigyxk6jp5bpct/Desktop.rar

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger to find the error yourself? It is a basic tool that every programmer needs to master and will be quicker than posting to a forum.

Comment: well figured out how to fix the FC's but the linearlayout doesnt become invisible